# Is it better for the robots to find html pages that do redirection or should I just use htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want some of the pages to be redirected back to the main page as 'params'.  These are not data or privacy sensitive, so I dont need to use the "session" variable.

I was thinking that it would be better for the robots to find physical html files.  So for example, I have **example.kiwi/downloads.html** containing

```
<meta http-equiv=="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.kiwi?mode=downloads" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script>window.location.href = "https://example.kiwi?mode=downloads"</script>
```

I assume that I can do the same with **htaccess**.  Is that better and how do I do it.  Being a sensitive file, I am trying not to experiment a lot with it.

Comment: 1. robots do not care at all whether the response to a request is based on a static file, some application logic or the rewriting logic inside your http server, actually they cannot really tell the difference and 2. robots certainly won't follow any JS based redirections. So go with redirection rules implemented in the http server's host configuration. If you have no acces to that you can use a disributed configuration file (".htaccess") which is a bit slower, but works _if the http server is configured to consider those_ ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is Webmastering/SEO question and is better suited to the Webmasters stack: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you create `downloads.html` simply to create the redirect? Or is this an existing page? Why not serve the content directly from the URL `/downloads.html` (using a URL-rewrite in `.htaccess`)? That would potentially be "better for the robots" (and users) than a _redirect_ - depending what the motives behind this are. (FWIW, Google _can_ follow "JS based redirections" (and meta refresh) - not that you would do it that way given the choice. @arkascha)

Comment: @MrWhite, I had done it for multiple reasons.  SEO tools kept telling me I had only one html page and no internal links.  I also wondered about the robot crawling.  Plus I wanted to be able to post links to files on the site, from my applications.  So I gave everyone dummy pages.  I know how to redirect all of these pages that I created, via htaccess.  I will have a look at the apache config file.  I hadnt realised it would be faster.